# border of PdfPTable - iText, java

Tags: itext

I need to have a border line for the PdfPTable but not for the cells inside. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

I have done this by putting this table inside a new cell. Now my question is how to add a line to split the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iText each PdfPCell has its own borders.

You can set the borders needed on the cell, and in case of a nested table do the same for that tables cells.

In your case you probably want to set the bottom border on the entire row that is to be separated.